# How to set the page pcon and loading animation in Gizmox's WebGui?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-web-gui

I have 2 problems regarding the design in the WebGui from Gizmox:

- How can I set a page icon for a form (or the entire website for that matter). I tried setting the Icon Property from the forms property grid but it does not work
- How can I change the loading page animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

- The icon property on the form has nothing to do with the icon of the web page. I had to specify "favicon.ico" file.

> When a VWG application runs, it will look for favicon.ico file on the
>   virtual folder in the following locations and in the following order,
>   and then pick or use the LAST one it finds: The root folder, Url will
>   be /favicon.ico The Resources\Icons folder, Url will be
>   /Icons.favicon.ico.wgx

From [here](http://wiki.visualwebgui.com/pages/index.php/How_to_use_favicon.ico_in_VWG_applications)

- To edit the loading animation, I had to add a new theme and overwrite the .html and the .css files for the Loading category. One important note is that I had to activate the theme from Project properties-> Registration-> Themes. There is also a bug. Every time I edit the theme, I have to rename the theme from the Registration tab. It took me a while to figure this out.